# Xamarin Forms iOS - App wont load in release mode

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, release

I am working on a Xamarin Forms app pointed at iOS, this works fine in debug, and on Android. Though when we are launching in release mode the app opens and closed immediately.

Monitoring the console for the iPhone I am seeing this error:

```
COSMCtrl _foregroundAppActivity incoming bundle <app name> has nil supplied UUID
```

Would this be the potential cause? I have a lifecycle class that is async being called which populates the MainPage, but not sure if it is a background thread being fired that is causing this issue like I assume or other potential causes.

There are other errors like:

```
 Advisor: No handle found for currently focused PID
```

and

```
Scene FBSceneManager/SceneID:<appname> update failed:
```

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by putting the app to SDK only linking.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows

Comment: Recommendation: Add a direct link to the section of the page on https://learn.microsoft.com which resolved the issue. This will help others see the resolution instead of searching the entire web page.